# Is it possible to loop a HashMap with limit?

Tags: java, loops, iterator, hashmap

This is my question since I'm programming a little more advanced java than I'm used to. So today I actually need some help from you! How to set a limit when lopping a `HashMap`? I have tried some codes to make the limit to one. My problem is that I want a Random entry from the HashMap, but when I use the Random function like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int max = list.size();
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(max);
```

And the problem is that sometimes it returns 'null'.
Then I tried this:

```
Iterator it = list.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
if(!stop)
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    atm = pairs.getValue();
    it.remove();
    stop = true;
}
```

But this crash my program. So, is there a better way of seting a limit for this?

Please come with examples, its the best way of learning. :)

Comment: It would help to know a little more about your intentions. Why do you want to iterate over a map? What will you do with the entries/keys/values while iterating? Which types does your Map manage? When do you want to stop?.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you want a random entry? What kind of problem are you solving? :)

Comment: Im making a quiz program with a list of quizes whitch are stored in a hashmap. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random entry from your hash map, try this one-liner:

```
Map.Entry<K, V> entry = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet()).get(Math.random() * map.size());
```

Comment: Incorrect number of arguments for type ArrayList<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer, Question>

Comment: @Edvin oops~ Fixed the error - it should be `ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Question>>`. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

if list is null then you need to put check on it like

```
int max = null != list ? list.size() : 0;
```

i hope this is what you looking for

Comment: The list has content, but when I do the code I wrote first, sometimes it returns "null"